# Unable to run fsck on boot Archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, boot, fstab, initramfs, fsck

I'm running Archlinux on **ODROID-N2+** with Petitboot (based on Uboot) bootloader. I followed the archlinux [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/fsck) to enable fsck on boot, but it still never runs.

I have **fsck** set as the last hook in **mkinitcpio.conf**. My kernel boot parameters are:

> root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait rw mitigations=off console=ttyAML0,115200n8 console=tty1  logo=osd0,loaded no_console_suspend net.ifnames=0 cma=800M clk_ignore_unused video=HDMI-A-1:1920x1080@60 **fsck.repair=yes fsck.mode=force**

My fstab entries look like this:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot  vfat  defaults,noatime,discard  0  0
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /      ext4  defaults,noatime          2  1
```

With some help from another question I increased a mount count via `tune2fs -C 50 /dev/mmcblk0p2` but there is still no mention of fsck in journal and the output of `tune2fs -l /dev/mmcblk0p2 | grep Last` looks like this:

```
Last mounted on:          /
Last mount time:          Thu Jan  1 00:00:07 1970
Last write time:          Thu Jan  1 00:00:07 1970
Last checked:             Sun Oct 25 03:13:29 2020
```

What am I missing?